# Get jQuery value of span into variable in C# file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function that gets the text of a timer that's in a `<span>`,

myJSFile.js:

```
function myFunction(){
     $("#timer").text();
}
```

I need to get this text in my C# method

myCSharpFile.cs:

```
public IActionResult myMethod(){
     int myText =  ????;
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Add the value to a hidden input on your form (and the value will POST on form submit), or send the value to server side using AJAX

Comment: @devlincarnate is there an example of this you can show me?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to add the value to a hidden input on your form, and it will get submitted with POST.

HTML

```
<span id="timer">3.44</span>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="hdnField" id="hdnField">
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    $("#hdnField").val($("#timer").text());
  $("form").submit();
});
```

The value will be available in POST as `hdnField`
Also, note:  the approach I've shown is to handle form submission in jQuery and not via a "submit" type button.  This is to allow jQuery to add the timer value to the form before it submits.  You may have some other event you want to use to trigger when the timer value is added to the hidden input.

Comment: Please make sure your form tag also comes with action and method attributes. Alternative way to get this over to the server would be to use cookies.